# Java Xpath How do I read in child elements?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following xml

```
<map>
    <textures>
        <texture id="1" name="texturetest" />
        <texture id="2" name="ground1" />
    </textures>
    <tiles standardheight="60" standardwidth="60">
        <tile id="1" textureid="2">
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="slope" value="0" />
                <attribute name="slopedirection" value="left" />
                <attribute name="friction" value="3" />
                <attribute name="traversable" value="true"/>
            </attributes>
            <boundingbox type="box" width="60" height="60" />
        </tile>
    </tiles>
    <moveables>
        <object id="1" name="player1" textureid="1" width="60" height="60">
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="score" value="0" />
            </attributes>
            <boundingbox type="box" width="60" height="60" />
        </object>
    </moveables>
    <background>
        <layer name="bg1" zdistance="30" />
    </background>
    <tilemap>
        <tile tileid="1" x="0" y="200" />
        <tile tileid="1" x="60" y="200" />
    </tilemap>
    <objectmap>
        <object objectid="1" initial_x="0" initial_y="0" initial_speed="50" initial_direction="90" />
    </objectmap>
</map>
```

I am using the following xpath to get moveables/object/

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) _path.evaluate("//map//moveables/object", nodesdoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
               NodeList attList = (NodeList) _path.evaluate("//attribute", nodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODESET);
               for (int x = 0; x < attList.getLength(); x++) {
                    String name = attList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                    String value = attList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
                    t.Attributes.put(name, value);

                }
            }
```

However this loops through all the "attribute" elements in the document rather than just the attribute elements within "object".

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Also if I call nodes.item(i).getChildNodes(); I get a null reference exception.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a dot at the beginning of the 2nd XPath to indicate that the Xpath meant to be relative to current `nodes.item(i)` :

```
NodeList attList = (NodeList)_path.evaluate(".//attribute", nodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODESET);
```